# How do I know if a Uri is empty?

Tags: android, android-camera, uri, android-camera-intent

I have an application where I need to be able to let the user decide how to put a picture profile, (camera or gallery). I have only one variable of type "Uri" but I do not understand how to reset it and make it EMPTY, or check if it is EMPTY. Because when I choose a picture I have to have the ability to change the photo if you do not like the one just put.
 I have tested as

```
 if (followUri.equals (Uri.EMPTY)) {...}
```

but the application crashes with a null point exception.

Answer (score 26):

Just check that Empty URI is not equal to followUri, this check includes check by `null`:

```
        if (!Uri.EMPTY.equals(followUri)) {
            //handle followUri
        }
```

Answer (score 13):

If the Uri itself is null then calling followUri.equals(Object) will result in a NPE. A better solution:

```
if (followUri != null && !followUri.equals(Uri.EMPTY)) {
    //doTheThing()
} else {
    //followUri is null or empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your app crashes with an NPE at that stage `followUri` is most likely `null`.

Also `Uri` objects are immutable, see here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html so you cannot "reset" it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `followUri != null` and after that you can check if it is empty, you get `NPE` because `followUri` is `null` don't you? After that you can set `followUri = Uri.EMPTY`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my 2 cents a null Uri is not treated as Empty. The value of Uri.EMPTY is "". Which can cause some confusion if you are expecting null == Uri.EMPTY to be true`enter code here`. A small kotlin code snippet as well :

```
 fun isUriEmpty(uri: Uri?):Boolean{
    return uri == null || uri == Uri.EMPTY
}
```